Why my Gunnera Manicata older leaves die?

It grows very fast. But only the youngest leaf is fine. Older leaves die after some time.
There's not any visible root rot symptoms. The plant likes the water, it grows in the swampland, so it's not possible to overwater it. The soil is very rich - it includes de-acidified peat, manure and leaf mould + a little bit of sand and regular soil taken from my garden.
It's the second year growing outside, this year is a bit better than previous, but still, old leaves eventually die which should not happen. Maybe soil is too rich or inappropriate, but I'm stuck, I have no idea what to do.
The only thing I'm sure, it's not lack of fertilizer.  In case lack of fertilizer, the plants are small and slow growing. Lack of sunlight is not a problem for Gunneras, they're doing right in the shade or full sunlight. In theory, too much sunlight could burn leaves, but it's not my case. Now, I'm not getting so much sunlight (autumn time) + even small leaves always shaded with larger ones die.
Any idea what causes that?

What a nice photograph!  I've added it to my desktop wallpaper rotation.

What part of the world do you live in?  What time of year do the leaves begin to show this browning?

I"m located in Poland, Central Europe. Autumn is coming, but there's still summer conditions (night lowest temp is above 10 °C, day highest is above 20).  Growing season is from April to the middle of October. Problems starts when 3rd leaf appear, after that, oldest leaf shows browning. It's from the growing season start. Today I found first leaf from April to be dead completly, I removed it.

Simple, it is the Circle of Life. Your lovely plant takes a heck of a lot of effort to produce a new bigger leaf that can reach closer to the sun and therefore photosynthesise better.
Plants control older leaf death with special hormones that stimulate the plant to deliver less nutrient to the older leaves, often due to them now being blocked from direct sunlight, and they will also get the leaf to give up nutrients back to the main plant for use in new leaf growth. It is called Senescence and it a normal and regulated process, so nothing to worry about.
There are many houseplants with big leaves that also do the same thing and can only sustain a maximum of 3 leaves at any time.
Autumn leaf fall is another more dramatic example of leaf senescence, in this case due to ensuring limited water is retained within the roots and trunks of large trees before winter frosts and sub-zero temperatures set in. This affects large leaf trees whereas conifer leaves are spiky and waxy and more adjusted to colder climes as well as limited light in the winter.

That's not that case. It should not happen. Nobody else get that. Older leaves should not die this way and so quickly. Something is wrong.

@user1209216: so it is lack of fertilizer (or Sun). Behaviour is the same: plants recycle materials from own old leaves, for new leaves (wintering: with an extra step to store nutrients in roots). (or root problem, so less nutrient for plant, so same behaviour). It is difficult to give the real reason: you should do some investigation (when did you fertilized last time, root are ok or too much water, moving soil near trunk help both cases)

Could to rich soil cause that?

@user1209216: I would say no in this case, but the old cut trunk may let us to think some rot roots which may disperse disease also to your plant.

What's the soil like? Is it rich in humus and damp most of the time, or does it dry out?

@user1209216 I've added the information from your comments to your question body, hope you don't mind!

@MackM - that's fine, I removed my comments
